# I have a .txt file and when I save it as a csv the leading 0s are no longer there

Tags: excel

I have a .txt file which needs to be .csv file.

So for example .txt File
00

When I open .csv file
0

Even after I format the csv file it still opens up with no leading 0

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

A `CSV` file is a text file saved with commas separating **unformated** values, created with a [basic set of rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules).

---

### Some of the basic rules for `CSV`'s:

Rules typical of these and other `CSV` specifications and implementations are as follows:

- `CSV` is a delimited data format that has fields/columns separated by the comma character and records/rows terminated by newlines.
- A `CSV` file does not require a specific character encoding, byte order, or line terminator format (some software does not support all line-end variations).
- All records should have **the same number of fields, in the same order**.
- Data within fields is interpreted as a sequence of characters, not as a sequence of bits or bytes.
  Adjacent fields must be separated by a single comma. However, `CSV` formats vary greatly in this choice of separator character. In particular, in locales where the comma is used as a decimal separator, semicolon, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or other characters are used instead.

  ```
  1997,Ford,E350
  ```
- **Any field *can be* quoted** (that is, enclosed within double-quote characters). Some fields must be quoted, as specified in following rules.

  ```
  "1997","Ford","E350"
  ```

---

- **Fields with embedded commas or double-quote** characters must be quoted.

  ```
  1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"
  ```

---

- Each of the **embedded double-quote characters** must be represented by a pair of double-quote characters.

  ```
  1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"" truck"
  ```
- The first record may be a "**header**", which contains column names in each of the fields (there is no reliable way to tell whether a file does this or not; however, it is uncommon to use characters other than letters, digits, and underscores in such column names).

  ```
  Year,Make,Model
  1997,Ford,E350
  2000,Mercury,Cougar
  ```

---

<sub>(More from the source: [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules).)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

*This method will also allow you to import a .txt file without changing the file type to .csv*

When you open a csv into excel it will workout what type of format the data should be and convert it for you, for example two zeros 00 will be reformatted as a number and automatically changed to a 0

To import a csv into excel and keep the data formatted in its original way you will need to use the Text import wizard:

Open excel, in the ribbon click on **Data**, select **From Text**, then browse for the csv file.

Make sure **Delimited** is selected and click **Next**, select the delimiter that is used within your csv, click on **Next**

For each column that contains the two zeros 00, select them and then change the Column Data Format to **Text**, when all column formats have been changed click **Finish**

In all columns where the formatting has been changed to text, you will have have to change the cell formatting manually for any data that should not be treated as text.